# unable to load public key

Tags: python, django, openssl, pyopenssl

I am having difficulties debugging a django/python application that requires a public key to be used to sign a certificate. 
1. I created a key in PEM format from my private key using the following command

```
openssl rsa -pubout -in ~/.ssh/id_rsa > samplePEMKey.pub
```

The key is given below

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA8K/LfOBi+QrINSseqWwc
JGo4uE49Dc42zF2Jwbmc6iXIln8AWX5M+yn15dYOXzbHGbopH8bpF9CsJ/DPHg87
D1At1XwAy5aR5w7pXE//5p/saW50Sm/eY6Nugs9hgAXUTcMMAEXCIG17dLoUzhwE
YdzuPm350h39bTmI7Fz95koTbsKJUi+6337GJ3cWKxMBkEmWvpGo4Nko01xtEnUZ
GweKexr1roE8jZPpzuNeUy+S5tvH5emyBIBdroBVxBtz1OUIoP0oAOrQ5RtRPAcT
TsSWjMtyF2gO5GxeMErRqnLAtWJs4QlaJacVnMMTAgRjrGkUZdsqngM/fjQXfeZV
SwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

In my python app I am using OpenSSL and trying to load the key using

```
pkey = crypto.load_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, samplePEMKey)
```

When running the django app I get the following error at the above line.

```
Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/snapshotuploader/single/
Django Version:     1.3.1
Exception Type:     Error
Exception Value:    

[('PEM routines', 'PEM_read_bio', 'no start line')]
```

Here's how I read the public key from the file

```
    file_path = '/home/XXXX/co/certserver/LicenseServer/home_folder/dldl/samplePEMKey.pub' 
try: 
  fin = open(file_path, 'r') 
except IOError: 
  return HttpResponse('IO Error opening uploaded file.') 
try: 
  samplePEMKey = fin.read() 
  fin.close() 
except IOError: 
  return HttpResponse('IO Error reading uploaded file.')
```

Appreciate any help in solving this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: At least `Crypto.Cipher.RSA.importKey()` works with pycrypto-2.5 with the key you supplied, so there should be nothing wrong with the key itself. How are you reading the key in to `samplePEMKey` variable?

Comment: file_path = '/home/XXXX/co/certserver/LicenseServer/home_folders/dldl/samplePEMKey.pub'
     
print pubKeyFile
try:
    fin = open(file_path, 'r')
except IOError:
    return HttpResponse('IO Error opening uploaded file.')
                
try:
      pubKey = fin.read()

      fin.close()
except IOError:
      return HttpResponse('IO Error reading uploaded file.')

Comment: Please edit your question to add the relevant code - also `pubKey` != `samplePEMKey`

Comment: Done. Thanks. Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a while to spot it, but you are trying to read a *public* key with a *private* key method. If you want to use `load_privatekey` you should use the original `id_rsa` as input.

I don't remember how to do the same with `OpenSSL.crypto`, but at least with the [pycrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) toolkit's `RSA` implementation your sample key imports just fine:

```
>>> kt = open("samplePEMKey.pub").read()
>>> from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
>>> key = RSA.import_key(kt)
>>> key
<_RSAobj @0x109916d40 n(2048),e>
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. I want to use samplePEMKey which is a public PEM key generated from id_rsa to sign a X509 request. I want to convert the sample public from a string read from a file to a format where it will be accepted when signing a X509 request. Can you point me to the function to use?

Comment: I am required to use OpenSSL.crypto